# Finding $ t(x)$ when velocity is linearly proportional to distance

Tags: calculus

Please forgive me if I missed where this has been asked/answered.

I'm working with a motion profile such that Velocity is linearly proportional to distance. Velocity as a function of x is:
$$
V(x) = m \cdot  x + b
$$
Where:

- $m = \dfrac{V_e-V_s}{L}$
- $b = V_s$
- $V_s$ is starting velocity.
- $V_e$ is ending velocity.
- $L$ is length of the line-segment
- When $x$ is zero, velocity is $V_s$.
- When $x$ is $L$, velocity is $V_e$.

I'd like to calculate time as a function of x.
I've tried the following (but there are several problems...)

Let $$V(x) = \frac{dx}{dt} = mx + b$$
$$
\Rightarrow \quad dt = \frac{dx}{mx+b}
$$
(Integrating...)
$$
\Rightarrow \quad t = \frac{1}{m} \ln(mx+b) + C
$$
This doesn't work as-is because if $(m\cdot x + b)$ is less than $1$, then $t$ (time) is negative. When $x= 0$, $t$ should be $0$.

I factored it to produce a "comfortable" $mx+1$ term, like so

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{ln((b)*(m/b)*x + 1)}{m}$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{[ln(b) + ln(\dfrac{mx}{b} +1)]}{m}$

$\Rightarrow\dfrac{ln(b)}{m} + \dfrac{ln(m/b*x +1)}{m}$

Now we can choose $c$ to get rid of the constant $\dfrac{ln(b)}{m}$, leaving

$$\Rightarrow\dfrac{ln(\dfrac{mx}{b} +1)}{m}$$

This is great, when $X$ is zero, then the equation returns $0$, however, it's undefined when "$b$" (starting velocity) is zero!

I'm stuck. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Indeed it seems awkward to calculate time as a function of $x$. How about you first calculate $x(t)$ (simple polynomial integration) and then consider the inverse function?

Comment: What I know about the motion is velocity as a function of position. I really need to know time as a function of position (or velocity). The answer isn't obvious to me, that's why I'm seeking help!

Answer (score 1):

If the starting velocity is $0$, then the object does not move at $t=0$, so it will not change $x$. Therefore the equation of motion in that case is $$x(t)=0$$You are trying to find the time it will reach $L$. That will never happen. :( You are trying to impose too many constraints

Comment: Starting velocity can be 0, in which case velocity equations is V(x) = mx.  However, that leads to t as a multiple of ln(x) which is undefined at x=0.

Comment: Take the derivative of your equation with respect to time. You will get that the acceleration is $a=mV$. When you are at $t=0$, you have $x=0$, $V=0$, and $a=0$. It means that the object will not move. If it does not move from $x=0$ how do you get to a different $x$?

Comment: First, I've described a real physical system. Velocity changes, though, velocity does not change linearly with time. Acceleration is not constant with respect to time, but it is not 0. x changes as a function of time. V =  m(x(t)). The derivative of x(t) with respect to time is not zero. Of course I don't know how to express x(t). If I did then I might be able to solve for t.

Comment: The derivative of x with respect to t is V. When x=0, then V=0. Also, the acceleration is zero. But these are only true if the particle passes through x=0. In fact, there is a physical phenomenon that has this velocity function. It is the  Stokes' drag. But if the velocity is zero, there is no acceleration, so the object cannot move